# Date.toLocaleString() return Invalid language tag: en_GB but Java.util.Locale Class return en_GB locale for UK

Tags: javascript, java

Java.util.Locale is return "en_GB" locale format for UK. when i use the same locale in this Date.toLocaleString() function which is returning Invalid language tag: en_GB . I just want to know why java and javascript behaving differently and what is the best solution for this

Answer (score 2):

> I just want to know why java and javascript behaving differently

Because they're different languages, each making their own decisions.

Admittedly, there is standard BCP 47 to identify languages and it's a pity that Java would choose to not use that.

However, java.util.Locale is a class, and therefore it doesn't "return" anything on its own. What you're observing is the result of letting something automatically convert an object of class java.util.Locale to String. That is done by calling the class' toString() method, which gives the result en_GB.

Again, it is a pity that the toString() method would have been implemented to produce anything else than the BCP 47 standard, but BCP 47 was published in 2009 and Java's java.util.Locale in 1997. Some programs were made to use it since its existence, and no one wanted these programs to break by arbitrarily changing methods' behaviors.

In conclusion, while there is value in expecting a best effort of implementing the principle of least surprise, it is still a rather poor practice to blindly rely on default automatically chosen conversions when expecting a specific format. (After all, this discussion is about specifying a language so that a date is formatted correctly, using this language.)

> and what is the best solution for this

Call `toLanguageTag()`